# NSUserDefaults won't store my NSStrings

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

i've tried to store a couple of strings in my NSUserDefaults... can't figure out what i'm doing wrong...

```
-(IBAction)addToFavorite:(id)sender {
    NSMutableArray* favoritedAlready = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"favorites"] mutableCopy];

NSLog(@"%@",favoritedAlready);


    if (![favoritedAlready containsObject:indexPathRowString]) {
        [favoritedAlready addObject:indexPathRowString];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:favoritedAlready forKey:@"favorites"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        favoritMarkerad.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"StarFilled.png"];}

    else {
        [favoritedAlready removeObject:indexPathRowString];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:favoritedAlready forKey:@"favorites"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        favoritMarkerad.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"StarEmpty.png"];
   }
```

when I try to load my array in another viewcontroller nothing happens..

```
(.h)
NSMutableArray *favorites_;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *favorites_;

(.m)
@synthesize favorites_;

-(void)makeData{

NSMutableArray* favoritedAlready = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"favorites"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    favorites_ = favoritedAlready;}
```

"NSLog(@"%@",favoritedAlready);" gives "2012-01-25 14:53:26.360 myApp[2752:1be03] (null)"
any ideas?

Comment: What doe you get when you `NSLog(@"%@", favoritedAlready);` right after the `mutableCopy` method?

Comment: "2012-01-25 14:52:07.385 myapplication[2714:1be03] (null)"

Comment: You're putting the strings into an array and storing that and your logic appears to be that if the string isn't already there then you add it, if it is already there then you remove it? Is that all accurate? And in terms of output, you're presumably not seeing 'Added favorite' when you expect to? Have you tried NSLogging the actual array to see what's in there as a diagnostic step?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Um, the array is empty atm, because I want to add strings sporadically. To begin with, the image never changes to "StarEmpty.png", even though i press the button twice, trice etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment, the problem is that there is no array in your `NSUserDefaults` named 'favorites' at any point. Probably you want to create one if it doesn't exist. So:

```
-(IBAction)addToFavorite:(id)sender {
    // get a mutable copy of the stored array, if there is one
    NSMutableArray* favoritedAlready = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
                     objectForKey:@"favorites"] mutableCopy];

    // if there wasn't a stored array then go ahead and create one to store
    if(!favoritedAlready)
        favoritedAlready = [NSMutableArray array];

    /* ... rest of stuff here ... */
    if (![favoritedAlready ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The NSMutableArray is (null) at the first point, so you could do this:

```
    if (favoritedAlready == nil) {
        favoritedAlready = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
```

right after the `mutableCopy` method.
So you'll be adding values to the `NSMutableArray` instead of adding it to a (null) object

---

*Just like what Tommy said*

Comment: @basvk sorry about usurping you; I just happened to be here immediately after Christoffer posted the comment that revealed the answer. +1 from me.